# I have plotted a Stern-Volmer Plot but cannot work out the fluorescence lifetime to be able to get the rate constant

Tags: photochemistry

I have plotted a stern Volmer plot and have my straight line equation. I understand that the gradient is kqtf but I need tf to work out kq but I don't have kd to do 1/kd.

How do I work it out?

Comment: Please give us more detail ! What are kq, kd and kqtf ? Which substance have you studied ? At which concentration ?

Answer (score 1):

In a Stern-Volmer plot the ratio of fluorescence yield $\varphi$ is plotted vs the quencher concentration $[Q]$ as $\varphi_0/\varphi_Q =1 +k_{SV}[Q] $ where  the gradient is the quenching constant which is $k_2\tau$ where $k_2$ is the 2nd order rate constant and $\tau$ the fluorescence decay in the absence of quenching.

(If you search this site you will find examples https://applying-maths-book.com/intro.html )